# Create 3D EEG topographical maps using Python

Tags: 3d, visualization

I have an EEG dataset and I want to create a 3D topographical map using Python. I have used the mne library to generate the 2D version but looking for a way to do an interpolated 3D mapping as well. Is there any existing packages or resources available to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use mne to do it.

From mne's tutorial (https://mne.tools/stable/auto_tutorials/evoked/20_visualize_evoked.html#d-field-maps):

```
# Assuming you have an Evoked object called evk and you have set the corresponding trans and subjects_dir variables
_map = mne.make_field_map(evk, trans=sample_data_trans_file,
                          subject='sample', subjects_dir=subjects_dir,
                          meg_surf='head')
fig = evk.plot_field(_map, time=0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't have evoked data so I can't really use mne.